# How do I use view helpers with ruby-ejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, view-helpers, ejs

I have a rails app that's using the ruby-ejs gem to compile js templates which I am then using in my backbone views.

I would like to use some view helpers to create form elements, such as select tags, within my templates. I found some EmbeddedJS View Helpers [here](http://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/wiki/ViewHelpers) but I don't know how to go about using them in my templates.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was not as difficult as I thought.

I simply included the ejs.js and view.js files from the EmbeddedJS project [here](http://embeddedjs.com/) and I was able to use the select_tag helper using the full namespace.

```
<%= EJS.Helpers.prototype.select_tag('example', selected_value, choices) %>
```

There's probably a better way to access the helper method. I'll post an update once I figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using express I recommend you use my version of ejs view helpers https://github.com/tanema/express-helpers

you can initialize them like this

```
var helpers = require('express-helpers')(app);
```

then in your ejs view use the select tag like this

```
<% 
    var choices = [ 
            {value: 1,text: 'First Choice' }, 
            {value: 2,text: 'Second Choice'},
            {value: 3,text: 'Third Choice'}  
        ]
%>
<%= select_tag('mySelectElement', 2,  choices) %>
```

which creates:

```
< select id='mySelectElement' value='2' name='mySelectElement'>
    < option value='1' >First Choice</option>
    < option value='2' selected='selected'>Second Choice</option>
    < option value='3'>Third Choice</option>
< /select>
```