# select_tag is not defined

Tags: node.js, ejs

Running node.js with Express and EJS for rendering here is my code:

```
<%
var choices = [ {value: '', text: ' ' }, 
            {value: 'HELD', text: 'HELD'},
            {value: 'CLEAR', text: 'CLEAR'}  ];
var selected = 0;
for (var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
if (manifest.z_customs_status.trim() == choices[i].value){
    selected = i;
    break;
}
}
select_tag('z_customs_status', selected,  choices)
%>
```

When the code runs I get

```
select_tag is not defined
```

as an error within EJS.
select_tag is documented here

```
https://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/wiki/ViewHelpers
```

Is EJS still viable for node development with Express?

Comment: Well, what is `select_tag`?

Comment: @hexacyanide I have adjusted the question to include the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like these aren't even defined in the [source](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs), which makes me wonder why it's on their wiki page. I did find from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9335959/724591) that there is the package called `express-helpers`, which when configured, allows access to all of the view helpers.

```
npm install express-helpers
```

In your app.js, configure it:

```
require('express-helpers')(app);
```

Finally, your view will be slightly different:

```
<% 
    var choices = [ 
        {value: 1,text: 'First Choice'}, 
        {value: 2,text: 'Second Choice'},
        {value: 3,text: 'Third Choice'}  
    ]
%>
<%- select_tag('mySelectElement', choices, { value: 2 }) %>
```

[The select_tag](https://github.com/tanema/express-helpers/blob/master/lib/express-helpers.js#L303) has the following parameters:

```
name
choices
html_options
  id      
  name
  value (selected value)
```

Comment: Thanks, Well it looks like TJ Holowaychuk wrote (is involved with writing) both EJS and Express so I guess he thought that the helpers would be better suited in Express.